# Is there any automatic Windows software to check status of website

Tags: windows, software-rec, website

Is there any automatic Windows software application to check status of website and alert me through mail or message or trigger am alarm..

Example:
Consider I am waiting to buy a new latest movie ticket online (through) and the ticket booking has not been informed properly (online booking is opening at a random time). In this situation I will be forced to slave for my PC to get the tickets. To avoid such situation, can you suggest me a software?

So I need a software which will alert me when the online booking is open.. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an application will heavily depend on the functionality and architecture of the web site, the technologies it uses, whether it provides RSS/API or not etc. Try these methods:

1. Check to see whether the web site provides notification options through subscription. For example, on this web site (Super User) one can subscribe to tags, and they can get daily/hourly emails when a question related to that tag is asked.
2. Check to see whether the web site has RSS/Atom functionality and they publish a post in these formats when online booking has opened. If so, you can subscribe to RSS/Atom feeds and you will get notified through your RSS/Atom application or web browser.
3. Check to see whether the web site provides an API for checking booking status at random/regular intervals. If so, you can develop or ask some friend or hire a developer to develop a simple application for you for that purpose. A small script or desktop/web app with email or notification functionality will suffice.
4. If it's a popular web site, probably someone has developed an extension, gadget, widget etc. Check Google.
5. Finally, try these websites, they seem to provide the service you're asking but I don't know whether the site you're mentioning is in their database, I haven't tried them. Use at your own risk!

   - http://www.frogfeed.com/
   - http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/pagetiki/
   - http://www.urlywarning.net/

Answer (score 2):

Check out **[Check4Change](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/check4change/)** - a [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/) addon...

> Check4Change (aka C4C) is a simple extension that allows you to periodically check a web-page for updates...

Hit the link for more info on how it works - it may not be *exactly* what you're looking for, but worth checking out.

Some other alternatives - at your own risk:

> http://www.rba.co.uk/sources/monitor.htm
>
> http://www.updatepatrol.com/

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it in years, and it appears to not have been updated in a while, but WebMon was pretty good while i was using it: http://www.markwell.btinternet.co.uk/webmon/

Answer (score -1):

There are some online tools like Visualping or Skenio, which allows you to select part of page and get email when this part change.